# How to add meta keyword in wordpress using yoast seo plugin.?

Tags: php, wordpress

i am using yoast seo wordpress plugin. but i dont know how to add meta keyword in wp-admin. i also try add my key word in **Focus keyphrase** but my keyword not display in front end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Advance Custom Fields plugin if you want to add it with out code, also you can add from top menu custom fields.
you can add it from code as well, also check this article it show how you can add from yoast seo plugin [https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/wordpress-custom-fields-101-tips-tricks-and-hacks/#:~:text=Simply%20create%20a%20new%20post,publish%20or%20update%20your%20post](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/wordpress-custom-fields-101-tips-tricks-and-hacks/#:%7E:text=Simply%20create%20a%20new%20post,publish%20or%20update%20your%20post).

Answer (score 0):

meta Keyword Removed from yoast Seo Plugin.
you can use advanced custom field or use from "tags" in a php code on header section.

Comment: You answer could be improved by linking to the official documentation which describes the removal of this feature. Also, you should provide an example of how to use the alternatives which you suggested.